# Не работает js скрипт с блоками, которые вывел с помощью PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Вывожу товары в корзину через ajax. Вывожу блоками, которые содержат картинку, описание, название, цену и счетчик количества товаров, это счетчик обрабатывается скриптом:

```
  <!-- Input Counter in the Cart -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var min = 1, max = 10;
      $('.number .number_controls > button').on('click', function() {
        var input = $(this).closest('.number').find('input');
        var value = parseInt(input.val());
        if ($(this).hasClass('nc-minus')) {
          if(value>min) value = value - 1;
        }
        if ($(this).hasClass('nc-plus')) {
          if(value<max) value = value + 1;
        }
        input.val(value).change();
      });
    </script>
```

Так вот этот скрипт не хочет работать. Если не выводить динамично, то все работает. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При использовании динамического контента, лучше работать относительно `body` или того контента, который не меняется, вот на примере вашего кода:

```
<!-- Input Counter in the Cart -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var min = 1, max = 10;
  $('body').on('click', '.number .number_controls > button', function() {
    var input = $(this).closest('.number').find('input');
    var value = parseInt(input.val());
    if ($(this).hasClass('nc-minus')) {
      if(value>min) value = value - 1;
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('nc-plus')) {
      if(value<max) value = value + 1;
    }
    input.val(value).change();
  });
</script>
```